# Change part of url after button click

Tags: javascript, url, replace, tabs

i have following Situation: 
Two Categories and one list of links.

Now i Need to Change a part of the URL, according to the category.
Used therefore 2 Buttons, to Switch between the categories.
Category A is Default.

```
<button id="Tab1">CategoryA</button>
<button id="Tab2">CategoryB</button>

<a id="link" href="http://www.test.com/CategoryA/Type1" target="_blank">Type1</a>
<a id="link" href="http://www.test.com/CategoryA/Type2" target="_blank">Type2</a>
<a id="link" href="http://www.test.com/CategoryA/Type3" target="_blank">Type3</a>
```

Inside the URL structure only the Category Part should differ, according to which button was clicked.
The URL change hast to happen immediately, so I thought to do it with javascript.

Tried Stuff like

```
$('#Tab1').on ('click', function (e) {
      link.href.replace....
```

but had no luck with it.

Would be nice if some could help

Comment: Posted answer which I think should help you out. Let me know if it's not what you were looking for though.

Comment: No problem. If it did solve your problem, would you mind marking my answer as accepted by clicking the tick on the left of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using jQuery, so here is a jQuery solution.

You can use jQuery's `.each()` to loop through each link, get the `href`, replace the category and then set the new `href`.

You should note that you cannot have repeating `id`s so I have changed them to classes. Here's the code.

```
$('#Tab1').on('click', function (e) {
    $( ".link" ).each(function( index ) {
        var newLink=$(this).attr("href").replace("CategoryB","CategoryA");
        $(this).attr("href", newLink);
    });
});

$('#Tab2').on('click', function (e) {
    $( ".link" ).each(function( index ) {
        var newLink=$(this).attr("href").replace("CategoryA","CategoryB");
        $(this).attr("href", newLink);
    }); 
});
```

and here's the updated html code, just with the ids changed to classes.

```
<button id="Tab1">CategoryA</button>
<button id="Tab2">CategoryB</button>

<a class="link" href="http://www.test.com/CategoryA/Type1" target="_blank">Type1</a>
<a class="link" href="http://www.test.com/CategoryA/Type2" target="_blank">Type2</a>
<a class="link" href="http://www.test.com/CategoryA/Type3" target="_blank">Type3</a>
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/QaJS9/1/